# Passing a DTO into a static domain 'Create' method

Tags: c#, dto

I'm wondering if it's bad practice to couple my DTO to my domain object like this and pass the object itself into `Create()`. Is it better to just give the parameters needed to perform the creation?

```
public static Playlist Create(PlaylistDto playlistDto, IUserManager userManager, IPlaylistManager playlistManager)
{
    Playlist playlist = new Playlist
        {
            Id = playlistDto.Id,
            Items = PlaylistItem.Create(playlistDto.Items, playlistManager),
            Sequence = playlistDto.Sequence,
            Title = playlistDto.Title,
            User = userManager.Get(playlistDto.UserId)
        };

    return playlist;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If the Playlist is an external dependency then it might make sense to use an extension method like:

```
public static Playlist Create(this PlaylistDto playlistDto, IUserManager userManager, IPlaylistManager playlistManager)
{
    Playlist playlist = new Playlist
        {
            Id = playlistDto.Id,
            Items = PlaylistItem.Create(playlistDto.Items, playlistManager),
            Sequence = playlistDto.Sequence,
            Title = playlistDto.Title,
            User = userManager.Get(playlistDto.UserId)
        };

    return playlist;
}
```

other than that, if the code is under your control, why not just make another constructor and do away with the static method